# Is recursion necessary in Quarkus/Mutiny?

Tags: java, redis, quarkus, smallrye

I'm trying to use Redis' [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan) feature which needs to called until the cursor returned is "0."

This approach works but feels overly complicated - is there a way to do it without recursion?

```
Uni<Object> callScanRecursively(String cursorNum, List<String> results) {
  List<String> args = new ArrayList<>(List.of(cursorNum, "MATCH", "*"));
  return reactiveRedisClient.scan(args)
      .onItem()
      .transformToUni(item -> {
            List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
            item.get(1).forEach(k -> {
              keysList.add(k.toString());
            });
            results.addAll(keysList);

            if (item.get(0).toString().equals("0")) {
              return Uni.createFrom().item(results);
            } else {
              String nextCursorNum = item.get(0).toString();
              return callScanRecursively(nextCursorNum, results);
            }
          }
      );
}

List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
String startingCursorRedis = "0";
callScanRecursively(startingCursorRedis, results)
    .subscribe()
    .with(item ->
        LOGGER.info(item)
    );
```

Comment: Are you asking because you expect doing it without recursion will make it less complex?

Comment: Yes but also I'm curious - I feel like I'm missing something in my understanding of Mutiny. It seems like there should be a way to do this with Multis. It looks like Spring Reactor supports a "Multi" that just emits the next key until there are no keys left without recursion https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisOperations.html#scan--

Comment: I support your curiosity. :) You can always replace the recursion with a loop, but a lot of times it's no cleaner, and often less elegant.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to use a loop with Quarkus because loops with block? Maybe I should be asking how to implement a nonblocking loop though I assume the answer is recursive async calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MultiRepeat` collecting the `ReactiveRedisClient#scan` results through a `Uni` emitter while a given condition, `response.get(0).toString().equals("0")` is still not met:

### Uni Emitter

```
Multi<String> callScan(String initialCursor) {
    final AtomicReference<String> cursorReference = new AtomicReference<>(initialCursor);
    return Multi.createBy()
            .repeating()
            .<AtomicReference<String>, List<String>>uni(
                    () -> cursorReference,
                    (state, emitter) -> reactiveRedisClient.scan(List.of(state.get(), "MATCH", "*"))
                            .subscribe()
                            .with(response -> {
                                if (response.get(0).toString().equals("0")) {
                                    cursorReference.set(null);
                                } else {
                                    state.set(response.get(0).toString());
                                }
                                java.util.List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
                                response.get(1).forEach(k -> keysList.add(k.toString()));
                                emitter.complete(keysList);
                            })
            )
            .whilst(o -> cursorReference.get() != null)
            .flatMap(l -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(l));
}
```

### Uni

Or even simpler if you don't need more control around the emitted items:

```
Multi<String> callScan(String initialCursor) {
    ReactiveRedisClientImpl reactiveRedisClient = new ReactiveRedisClientImpl();
    final AtomicReference<String> cursorReference = new AtomicReference<>(initialCursor);
    return Multi.createBy()
            .repeating()
            .uni(
                    () -> cursorReference,
                    (state) -> reactiveRedisClient.scan(List.of(state.get(), "MATCH", "*"))
                            .invoke(response -> {
                                if (response.get(0).toString().equals("0")) {
                                    cursorReference.set(null);
                                } else {
                                    state.set(response.get(0).toString());
                                }
                            })
                            .map(response -> {
                                List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
                                response.get(1).forEach(k -> keysList.add(k.toString()));
                                return keysList;
                            })
            )
            .whilst(o -> cursorReference.get() != null)
            .flatMap(l -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(l));
}
```

Comment: The main thing I was missing was the repeating() method - that is very useful.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. This helped me a lot w/ paginating a cursor based GraphQL API. Just a note: Mutiny [implements](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.0.0/guides/rx/) its own alternatives to `map` and `flatMap`. Instead of using `flatMap` after `whilst`, you could use `onItem().disjoint()` (see [mutiny docs on paginating apis](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.0.0/guides/pagination/)).